# How to filter std::list and remove non-matching items comparing to another list?

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove elements which are not matching with elements from another list.

For example I have `std::list<MyClass> mainList` which contains something like this:

```
ID      Number
-------------
1       100
2       200
3       200
4       100
5       300
```

And I have one more `std::list<long> itemsForFiltering` which contains: `100, 300`.

And here I am trying to remove all elements from `mainList` which are not in `itemsForFiltering`.

```
int filterList(std::list<MyClass> &mainList, std::list<long> &itemsForFiltering)
{
    mainList.remove_if([](MyClass &val)
    {
        return val.Number != itemsForFiltering;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

This part probably requires one more lambda function `return val.Number != itemsForFiltering;` but I am not sure how to make it. So any help is appreciated.

After calling this function I should get this in `mainList`:

```
ID      Number
-------------
1       100
4       100
5       300
```

Comment: It's strange that you have lists here, did you mean to use vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it more efficient, you can start by creating an unordered set of the items to filter:

```
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;
...

auto itemsForFilteringSet = unordered_set<long>{itemsForFiltering};
```

Now you can filter using

```
mainList.remove_if([&](MyClass &val)
{
    return itemsForFilteringSet.find(val) == itemsForFilteringSet.end();
});
```

This will make the complexity linear in the sum of the lists' lengths, instead of their product.

Comment: Looks like a nice solution but compiler complains about `unordered_set not found`... Even after I include it. Complete error:  `<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::list<_Ty>' to 'std::unordered_set<_Kty>`

Comment: @harunB10 Modified a bit both parts (`using` and contemporary-style ctor call). LMK if it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```
mainList.remove_if([](MyClass &val)
{
    return val.Number != itemsForFiltering;
});
```

This comparison checks if the `val.Number` is not equal to the entire list `std::list<long> itemsForFiltering`. You probably meant to check that the list contains the val such as:

```
mainList.remove_if([&](MyClass &val)
{
    bool matchfound = false;
    for(auto& l: itemsForFiltering) {
        if ( val.Number == l) {
            matchfound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return !matchfound;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I've meant that... But here in for loop I get this - `an enclosing-function local variable cannot be referenced in a lambda body unless it is in the capture list`.

Comment: @harunB10 `mainList.remove_if([&](MyClass &val)` will fix that, basically you need to capture the variable into the lambda either by value (=) or by reference (&). See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of 0RR's answer:

```
mainList.remove_if([&](MyClass &val)
{
    for(auto& l: itemsForFiltering)
        if ( val.Number == l)
            return false;
    return true;
});
```

Not sure if it would actually result in any difference in the binary, but it prevents the use of an additional variable and might be easier to read, but that is a batter of taste.